# Can uncle blocks be avoided by adding a lock to transaction instance once a miner picks it up?

Tags: uncle-blocks, reward, balancer

In case of the uncle blocks, to wait until a longest branch is built and to discard the uncles while still rewarding the miners because they spent their computational resources to help secure the network, I'm wondering why can't we have a lock for the transaction instance that once a miner picks it up, set it and so all the clutter can be avoided. What is the feasibility of this and does duplicate mining really provide additional security to the network?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'd like that batch of selected transactions to be locked to the first miner that picked them up ? Just to be sure to understand your question before answering it.

Comment: Not the batch of transactions, just the initial one that triggered the forking

Comment: That's precisely my issue with your question, a fork is defined on the blockchain by having several blocks at the same level, the transactions are irrelevant here, that's why I'm not sure to understand your proposal

Comment: This is a good question! At what level are you suggesting we "lock" transactions? Like if I'm a small time miner that can mine 1 block a week, and I pick up a transaction, will that transaction been locked away from anyone else? So the transaction would need to wait an avg of 3 to 4 days to get through?

Comment: @hroussille https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcX7OJ-L8XQ I got this question while watching this. Maybe this will help you get my point. But I'm just concerned with the initial duplication of the block that a single transaction would have caused.

Comment: @ZiyadEdher That is a valid point. If my point is feasible then we can think about rules to handle such scenarios I guess.

Comment: @JSDEV The problem then is to have a "lock" you need some sort of repository, where all miners will check who has the lock for a particular transaction. So the problem are no longer blocks but "locks". If you use a central repository then it is no longer blockchain because it lacks decentralization. If you use a decentralized repository, you have exactly the same problem again but this time with "locks". How will you coordinate miners access to this decentralized repository? Who has priority to take a lock?